# Can a Gentile eat chometz in your home during Pesach?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven

Let's say Gentile construction workers come to your home on Hol Hamo'ed (emergency construction, such as a storm blew off a major part of your roof and if not immediately fixed, it would be dangerous to live in your home.) They bring their own chametz lunch. Can they eat it on your home? If so, what precautions, if any, do you need to do so that you don't end up with chametz in your home?

Comment: emergency construction??? Like Pikuach Nefesh? Anything necessary should be fine then

Comment: possible/partial dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51098/759

Comment: Actually I'm going to put this on hold as a dupe until you remove any duplicate parts. Ping me to let me know what you've done so.

Comment: @DoubleAA see edits

Comment: Even if the construction is PIKUACH NEFESH, the chometz surely isn't.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies It can be if a tornado destroyed your home and chametz is the only available food around for many days.

Comment: Given that in the other question, it's stipulated that the gentile helper is going to be in the house, I don't see how special circumstances making it imperative for the construction workers to be in the house distinguishes this question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses That's why I'm OK with this being a dupe.